# Doubts on Hive external table insertion and update

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

I've seen from Hive 0.14 [insertions and updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL) are available. My first question is: do insertions and updates work for external tables?

If they do, how it works? I guess related HDFS files have to be modified by appending new lines and by updating involved lines, respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing different about external tables is the location and whether the data is dropped with the table

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hive 0.14 supports inserts/ deletes. Having said that, it comes with a number of limitations. Currently there is no support for external tables. Please see here for the full list of limitations - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions